# Why does few analyzer rules have their effective severity set to suppressed in .NET4.6

Tags: .net, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

After adding code quality NuGet packages, I can see that by default, the effective severity level for some rules is set to suppress. But their default severity level remains warnings.

[Severity set as suppress not as warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7DE.png)

How can I set the severity for all the rules as a warning?

I tried using AllEnabledByDefault in .csproj file. But it is not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

[Enabling Analyzer Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG4ai.png)

It looks to me like there is no way to enable all the default disabled analyzer warnings. All we can do is to enable the needed warnings using :

dotnet_diagnostic..severity =